# Getting duplicate values when joining .csv spreadsheet to .shp map layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, csv, spreadsheet

I need to join .csv/spreadsheet data to the .shp map layer. The join itself isn't a problem with same join & target values (building) but some data goes missing because of duplicate values.

For example, if the map data is buildings and spreadsheet contains information about workers: info from workers from the same building gets missed because the join is done by the value of the building to combine spreadsheet to the building map layer.

How do I present all the information about workers in the map even if the info is from the same building?

The join isn't possible with any other value.

For example

[image]

Comment: I guess you're using `join attributes by value`? Have you tried changing the join-type from `one-to-one` to `one-to-many`?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am fairly new to QGIS so where do you change this? I choose the layer from the panel, and click ''joins'' from the properties (add vector join). There I only need to fill ''join layer''; ''join field'' and 'target field''. Where can I change the join type? I'm using version 2.18 but I guess they are all quite similar.

Comment: Just checked, this works in QGIS 3.4, but not in 2.18. For 2.18 you'd have to work with SQL, I guess. I'd suggest anyway, that you upgrade to 3.4, the latest LTR.